# Getting a string within a string Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string

<del>I have an html page with a few divs on it. Each div has one of these classes: tabCurrent, tabVisit, tabNext. I'm trying to search the string.className and get a substring that starts with "tab" but returns the full word, tabCurrent, etc.</del>

<del>I've tried various functions such as string.match(/tab\w/), string.exec(), string.includes(). A lot of the functions that find the string within a string, only return a Boolean..Or, you need to know the index and length already. Is there a good way to do this without using a while loop and starting at a known index and continuing until a white space to build the string?</del>

**EDIT:** I've reworded my question

Say I have a string

```
var className = 'someClass tabCurrent tabVisit someOtherClass';
```

I want to get the classes that start with "tab". I'm trying to achieve this using string.match(). Is there a regex expression to pass in that would achieve this?

Comment: can it be jQuery?

Comment: 'tried various functions' -> please include some of your tries.

Comment: I've avoided jQuery this far, I'm only building a single form for a website and didn't want to keep the library of files small, but I haven't even researched what it takes to set that up.

Comment: `hereGoesYourString.match(/^(tab\w*)/gi)` returns e.g. "tabCurrent" but not "currentTab".

Comment: Please edit your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I've reworded my question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one `tabSomething` class you may use a match like this:

```
'someOtherClass tabVisit'.match(/\btab.+?\b/); //['tabVisit']
```

For multiple matches you have to enable the global `g` flag on the regex.

Comment: I read that '.' in regex means to find a single character, so what does it do in your expression?

Comment: @slanden `.` matches any characters (except a few, you can google). Then `+` means one or more of the preceding token and finally `?` means that the match will not be greedy and will stop as soon as the minimum pattern length is discovered. So basically, match any characters until you hit the first word boundary.

Comment: Perfect, so the minimum pattern length is determined by \b ?

Comment: @slanden Exactly. If it finds one word boundary, it will not continue and see if there's another one further in the string that could still fulfill the match.

Comment: Thank you, this was the ticket!

Comment: @slanden Np, for multiple matches just enable the `g` flag on the regex.

Comment: yes I made that change right away as well as changing '.' to '\w' for the case that i have a "tab" class and didn't want it in my result, but the concept and understanding you provided was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

1. Collect all divs
2. Loop each div and get its className
3. Split className to array of classes
4. Match each class against regex that validates it starts with tab: `/^tab/`
5. If it matches insert to array

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var classRegex = /^tab/;
var matchedClasses = [];

for (var i = 0; i< divs.length; i++) {
  var currentDiv = divs[i];
  var className = currentDiv.className;
  var classNames = className.split(' ');
  for (var curClass of classNames) {
    if (curClass.match(classRegex)) {
      matchedClasses.push(curClass);
    }
  }
}

console.log(matchedClasses)
```

```html
<div class="tabCurrent"></div>
<div class="wrapper tabOther tab-three"></div>
<div class="different"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Z, however, this regex won't work in my case because the className contains other classes so "tabCurrent" will likely not be at the beginning of the string.

Comment: So what are you trying to do? To collect all divs that have a class that starts with tab (even if it is say the third class)?

Comment: @slanden Please check my solution now. Does this work for you? is this what you meant?

Comment: Negative, I have the div. I just want to extract a substring from the className string. i.e. className = 'tom tabCurrent hide pg';    string2 = 'tabCurrent';

Comment: @ Slanden did you see my update? It now collects the classes the way you asked

Comment: what I meant is your var classRegex = /^tab/; would only return tabCurrent if it was at the beginning of className string right?

Comment: No... Because I am taking this `className = "someClass tabOther tabThree"` and spliting it into an array like this: `var classes = ['someClass', 'tabOther', 'tabThree']`. Therefore now every value in this array will have to start with tab.. If it does you get it in the final result..

Comment: @ Z-Bone Ah, I see. Yes this would very well work. I was looking for a simpler solution using regex. I'm not sure what regex compiles down to, to compare performance, but if not using regex a similar way to yours I was thinking of doing was something like: `var originalString = 'someClass tab tabCurrent tabVisit someOtherClass'; var start = originalString.indexOf("tab"); var i = start; while( i !=' '){i++;} var newString = originalString.substring(start, i);`  some syntax may be wrong and it wouldn't get all cases, but that's just a gist.

Comment: @slanden so why not use my working scenario  which is also more efficient? Anyways good luck to you :)

Comment: I was just sharing my thought that I had a similar way but didn't go with it because I wanted a simpler way. What I'm using now is this: `var originalString.match(/tab\w+?\b/g);` It's a lot less code, is it less efficient than your solution? If so, what brings you to that conclusion?

Comment: I was talking about the previous example you gave me, which uses indexOf, regex, substring and a while loop.

Comment: ah, I meant to convey that I wanted to use the simplest combination of function and regex, and avoiding your solution and my other solution altogether as yours is more efficient but both are more complex than I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This will return "tabCurrent" for `<div class="tabCurrent">`:

`div.className.match(/tab.+/g);`